# Implement's Empowerment + Shield

Tags: pathfinder-2e

[Thaumaturges](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=22) gain 2 extra damage per die from Implement's Empowerment feature to compensate for the lack of 2 handed weapons:

> [...] You don't gain the benefit of implement's empowerment if you are holding anything in either hand other than a single one-handed weapon, other implements, or esoterica, and you must be holding at least one implement to gain the benefit.

Can a Shield be counted as a one-handed weapon?
If I use a jaws or tail unarmed attack, have a Shield in one hand and the other is handling the implement, do I benefit from Implement's Empowerment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Implement Empowerment does not work with a shield out

Implement Empowerment's restriction isn't about having a hand free. It seems to be about restricting the balance of offense and defense/versatility. It provides a damage bonus when you have nothing *other* than a weapon or your class items out.

Shields can be used to make Strikes under specific circumstances, but even then they are something "other than a single one-handed weapon" meaning that it does not qualify.

[Shield Bash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=40) even specifically calls out that it is not a weapon. [Shield Spikes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=42) and [Boss](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=41)es actually do count as [Attached] weapons, but then they are not the only thing you are holding.

Comment: yeah, this is the answer I was coming to. Even a spiked shield is "weapon *and* something else", so I don't think it works. This funnily enough keeps them balanced with other martials, in a way - if they want to use a shield, they'll be brought down to normal 1H weapon damage. Without one (and with Implement Empowerment), they are actually doing 2H weapon damage.

Comment: Could be worth referencing [shields bashes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=40) as those specific circumstances, like the opening "A shield bash is not actually a weapon"